# How to have my own ID in my table with custom numbers Auto-Increment

Tags: mysql

Hello I have made a Database with MySQL which has multiple tables among them i have a table with

Number of columns the first column is **ID** that i want to this be **custom number + text also 
AUTO INCREMENT** EX: **StudentID = 20140211-R01**

Is there any way to achieve this one?

Comment: There is. Use two columns, one for the number and another one for text. When you display the data, concatenate the two. If you want that in one column, then without trying to be rude I have to suggest that you get a few books about relational databases and especially MySQL and try to see why that's one of the dumbest ideas one can have.

Comment: Even if you insert auto_increment manually then it will allow you to do it..but why you are making it auto increment as it does no seem your requirement instead you can just make it primary key...

Comment: If you're using this as a primary key, be aware of the performance overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use query

`SELECT CONCAT(column1,column2) as StudentID  FROM tableName;`

Comment: how can i make it Auto_Increment

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.id2 =  '20140211-R' & NEW.id;
END
```

untested and definately, almost certainly incorrect but you need TRIGGERS.

However - if the custom number and text are static why not just add them on afterwards?

```
$StudentID = '20140211-R' . $row['id];
```

(assuming that its PHP of course!)

Comment: i did not get this line...SET NEW.id2 =  '20140211-R' & NEW.id;.. what are the NEW.id2 and NEW.id ?

Comment: NEW is needed when doing operations before inserting, there is also an OLD -> (taken idrectly from link) Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL extensions to triggers; they are not case sensitive. <- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html